# Same function name for two very different function throwing error

Tags: apex

I have a Apex class

```
public class Orignal{
    public static void exmapleFunc(String p1, String p2) {

        String strJSON = 'body';
            Example.exmapleFunc(p1, p2, strJSON, 'url','host');
    }
}
```

which has an  function name `exmapleFunc` and another static class with the same function name , but the complier is giving me error

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void exmapleFunc(String, String, String, String, String) from the type Example
```

even though the function does exists. Why am i getting this error? and can i resolve it without changing names?

**Edit:**

The Example class

```
public class Example{
    public static void exmapleFunc(String p1, String p2,String p3 , String p4 ,String p5) {
System.debug('im doing something useful');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class is looking for `emcampleFunc`. Can you confirm if it's not a typo. Additionally, the error should also be point you to the line & file where error exists.

Comment: sorry , my bad typo while typing the question , but the error leads me to the `Orignal` class function

Comment: @AkashJain, Is your method in another class have the same parameters `exmapleFunc(String, String, String, String, String)`. Here you are giving the parameters all as String

Comment: You're getting the error becuase you're calling a method from the `Example` class, where is that class?

Comment: @rael_kid i'm not actually

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala added the Example class

Comment: @AkashJain, I don't see any issue in the classes and I am able to save them successfully. Can you let us know if you are not able to save the class or are you getting this when you are calling the class. If so let us know how you are calling this class.

Comment: Works for me - I got *"im doing something useful"* in my debug log after calling `Orignal.exmapleFunc('Blah', 'blah');` from Anonymous Apex. A) Are both of your classes within the same namespace? B) Are both top-level classes? (Because `static` can only be used on top-level methods.)

Comment: C) Depending on where you are developing these, have you actually saved them or deployed them? (When working in VS Code, I have more than once saved a file then forgot to deploy it, and I have more than once deployed one that I *thought* I had saved but had not really saved.)

Comment: Ok , maybe a bit of background here , i'm actually using IntellJ maybe that is throwing the error , i will update once i deploy to the server and see if the error still persists

Comment: **Update** ok it's working fine now , like @Moonpie said , i had not deployed in the server ,but after deployment it started working fine , i keep confusing Apex with Java (as i'am very new to Apex) this will take a long time to get used to.
Thanks everyone